# Dynamic Attributes

Tags: magento-1.7, attributes, extensions

I'm sorry for posting here but as the Magento Forum still isn't working I'll try my luck here.
Is there anyway in having dynamic attributes. To explain what I mean is that for example I would have two attributes with values and would like to have a third attribute that creates a total of these two or a form that then creates a sum in the with the third (dynamic) attribute.

Like have length, height and the third attribute then calculates the overall dimension. Or you have a price, special price and the third attribute should show the percentage of the the discount.
Also this could also be only used in the backend to show the margin of a product.

Some thing like that. Is there any extension or a way in achieving this? I couldn't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an observer for the `catalog_product_save_before` event.
Your observer can look something like this:

```
public function calculateSomeValue($observer) {
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $val1 = $product->getData('attr1');
    $val2 = $product->getData('attr2');
    $val3 = some logic here that takes into account $val1 and $val2
    $product->setData('attr3', $val3);
}
```

Of course this will only work when you save a product by calling `$product->save()`. But there are other ways of saving products: import, updateAttributes...

I would created a cron that runs the above script for all the products. So each time you have new products the next time the cron will run, it will fill in your values.

Comment: do you have any idea how to assign value to an existing product attribute ? The attribute is additional and form under a set and group. ->setData("key", value) is not just working :(